# Facebook login from my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I need to implement login using facebook from my site.

Please give me a sample code in php

Regards

Arun Krishnan G

Answer (score 1):

Facebook provides all the documentation and sample code you need:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Comment: Hi thanks ,'appId' => '',
  'secret' => '',what is this appid and secret?Will you please make clear about this?

Comment: You find that at developers.facebook.com log in and read the tutorials and your admin panel